# Fail to delete pointer - unexpected behavior

Tags: c++

I trying to delete pointer that i define - and somehow i see that i can continue the using of this 'deleted' pointer and i can't understand why

Line 3 as far as i understand must cause an exception - and i see that result contain the right return value of the method 'Sum' of class 'c1'

```
1  Class1* c1 = new Class1();
2  delete(c1);
3  auto retult = c1->Sum(1, 4);  // expect this line will cause exception
```

Comment: *"Line 3 as far as i understand must cause an exception ..."* - Nope. Undefined Behavior has *infinite* consequences

Comment: line 3 must not do anything, it just has undefined behaviour and can do just about anything

Comment: _"Line 3 as far as i understand must cause an exception"_ According to whom? Where did you hear that?

Comment: ok .... still learining C++ ..... please explain .. i think line 2 delete the c1 object so line 3 must cause an exception  -   no ?

Comment: guys ... please explain why delete some pointer and using it does not cause exception

Comment: @Yanshof -- why would it cause an exception -- all you did was to free the memory -- the pointer and the freed memory probably still have the same values.  C++ != Java

Comment: @Yanshof -- Unlike other computer languages that you may have used, `C++` has something called *undefined behavior*.  When you make mistakes like using a pointer that was previously deleted, you cannot predict what will happen.  The program may work, crash, work sometimes and crash another time, work on your computer while it fails on another, etc., etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks !!! 

now i understanding this. i just begin to learn cpp - and this issue i maybe missed

Comment: But how can i delete a pointer in a way that i will get an exception on this ?

Comment: You can't. C++ has a policy of not making the programmer pay for what they do not use, and a validity test before every pointer access with be a performance hit on every program that got it right and doesn't need such checking. What you can do is implement the check yourself: Follow the `delete c1;` with a `c1 = nullptr`. and then place a `if(c1 == nullptr) throw badpointereception;` ahead of all accesses. Strongly recommend wrapping the checked pointers with a class and guarding all deletes, and accesses with a method that makes sure the checks are observed.